How to use the Bigtable cbt CLI while connected to a VPN?
I am using the Bigtable cbt CLI locally to manage my Bigtable instances and tables.  When doing this from my home network, I have no issues.  When attempting to run commands while connected to a VPN (PIA) I receive a RPC connection error.  See below examples:
command:
cbt -instance test-instance createtable test-table
response:
rpc error: code = Unavailable desc = connection error: desc = "transport: authentication handshake failed: write tcp [2600:8804:8242:be00:9da3:2d9:e624:a71c]:54747->[2607:f8b0:4009:804::200a]:443: write: broken pipe"
other response that has occurred:
rpc error: code = Unavailable desc = connection error: desc = "connection error: desc = "error reading server preface: EOF"
Thank you for any help!

Did you have time to check my answer? It helped you to solve your issue? If not,I am happy to assist further.What should I do when someone answers my question?

Hi @ImranPremnawaz - Unfortunately I am still encountering issues.  To try and troubleshoot this, I am looking into the source code for the cbt CLI here: https://github.com/googleapis/cloud-bigtable-cbt-cli

Could you please let us know if the issue is still persisting? If yes please let us know so that we will be assisting you further.For getting cbt CLI source code I can see that you are redirecting to the correct github however let us know if you have tried the steps provided by us like updating cbt CLI and checking VPN configurations?

The RPC error you are encountering indicates a problem with communication between your local client (cbt CLI) and the bigtable service. And if it occurs while connecting to a VPN then it may be caused due to several factors:

VPN configuration: Ensure  that your VPN allows traffic to cloud services because some VPNs may block certain ports and protocols.

Split tunneling: This is used to route only specific traffic through VPN while sending other traffic directly through your home network.

IPV6 issues : Also this error message indicates an IPv6 address.Try disabling IpV6 on your device  or VPN settings to see if it resolves.

Update cbt CLI: Ensure that you are using the latest version of the cbt CLI as the updates may fix connection issues.

Firewall settings: Check your firewall settings both on your local machine and VPN whether they are blocking the connection.


Also  you can check this for the Status codes and their use in gRPC.
Note : The unavailable error can often relate to network issues, server overload or maintenance.
